# 英語が残っている: 質問投稿をしようとしたときのポップアップ

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

質問投稿をしようとしたときに出てくるポップアップに英語が残っています。これらの string は Transifex/Traducir のデータベースには現状無いようです。

- タイトルを書こうとしたとき: "How to ask" "learn more"
- 本文を書こうとしたとき: "How to format" "learn more"
- 投稿画面下部の「文章の整え方」: "back"

### スクリーンショット

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: @Shog9 Has this bug resolved? I can't find the strings on ja.traducir.win even now.

Comment: The strings should be the same as the titles of the sections they link to - so, they should already have been translated.